# How do you know what Node.js code will run on the browser?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, browserify, client-side, flux

I'm learning how to use Flux and I encountered the following line in the documentation: "We can use Node's EventEmitter to get started with a store."

I understand that you can use things like Browserify to do the bundling and minifying, grabbing all the dependencies that Node code has to make the bundled browser-compatible JS file. But what's bugging me right now is how you know what you can do this with. How do we know what Node code we're allowed to use in the browser?

Comment: Node code running in browser? nodejs is server side runtime. if you mean node modules, then you can check the package.js and make sure it doesn't have server specific dependancies

Comment: typically you would reuse the framework agnostic js and leave the node specific code on the server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, first of all let's consider that when in node you have

- JavaScript [modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) that are the 3rdParty modules written in JavaScript (ECMA5, ECMA6 and even TypeScript or CoffeScript) etc;

  - Node built-in module. Those are node [Core modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_core_modules) like `fs`, `path`, `util`, etc.
  - native compiled module called [Addons](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) that are are
    dynamically-linked shared objects, written in C or C++;

Then you have the packager / module bundlers

- [Browserify](http://browserify.org/)
- [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/)

the transpilers i.e. source to source compilers that typicall will handle syntax tranforms like

[Babel.js](https://babeljs.io/) that shims modern JavaScript to legacy engines

and the techniques

- [ECMA5 Shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) to support legacy JavaScript engines
- [HTML5 Cross-Browser Polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills)

Because you need to do polyfills if you want to transform not only syntax but even globals (like the Promise), so you combine transpiler to polyfill having like [babel-polyfill](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/)

Finally we have different kind of modules design patterns (modules format) to be handled for the bundling process:

- [AMD](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD) modules format
- [CommonJS](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/CommonJS) modules format

and formats that are not in those ones that must be bundled/shimmed  - where possible  - through custom [loaders](https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html).

That said, native modules will not run in the browser: you cannot bundle a native module through Webpack. Ordinary modules will, but not all. This is due to several reasons. There are some specific methods that cannot be "browserified" or "webpacked". Let's take as example `fs`. Can you put this built-in module in the browser? There are some abstraction for that called [brfs](https://github.com/substack/brfs), that are transforms for built-in node apis `fs.readFileSync()` and `fs.readFile()`, so you will do

```
$ browserify -t brfs example/main.js > bundle.js
```

to get

```
var fs = require('fs');
var html = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/robot.html', 'utf8');
console.log(html);
```

This will not work for every non built-in modules, in the `npm` modules jungle, so WebPack has a `module.noParse` option to exclude Addons modules, non supported modules, etc. - see [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2799) about that.

So you have to look at the [list of the transforms](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/wiki/list-of-transforms) that means you can apply this transform to `browserify` to obtain like the `fs` transform mentioned above.

So that said, how do you know that a certain module will run in the browser? When you design your web application and Node backend you have to do opportunistic design choises to design shared modules/library that will run in both the environment, so being shimmed/packed at some point, like object models, application logic, etc., other modules that will deal with the File System I/O or will use native addons, so that will work in the server only, packing through wrappers it's possibile, but the behavior will look differently, as we have seen in the `fs` example above, and web specific modules, so it's a design matter.

A note can be added about networking modules i.e. node `http`, `https` that thanks to library abstractions like node [request](https://github.com/request/request) will run everywhere or using specific transforms like [http-browserify](https://github.com/substack/http-browserify).